# Pass Value To Another Page Using Post Method

Tags: php

I want to pass these values to final page. How can i catch value  in final.php?

```
<form action="final.php" method="post">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="99999" />
```

Comment: I think i have used. and i need help for final.php to catch the value when user navigate from first page to final.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write code like this

```
//html
<form action="final.php" method="post">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="99999" />
<button type="submit"/>

//final.php
...........
$val = $_POST['id'];
echo $val;
```

then you can get the input value in final.php

Answer (score 1):

In laravel you can get from request object.

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $id = $request->input('id');

    //
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is using `$_POST['id']` in final.php page to get value.
http://jslearning.info/json-php/#PHP_Method_POST